# MDSplus configuration: How to Change the Start Shot Number in an MDSplus tree?

Tags: database-administration

When creating a new MDSplus tree, it's possible (or perhaps even required) to specify the smallest shot number for which data can be stored in the tree.  Shot numbers are just index values identifying experiments that produce data to be stored.  I'm working with an MDSplus tree now and found out that data for earlier shot numbers are available and would like to lower the configured limit for my tree so that I can store those earlier datasets.  I didn't initially set up the tree, however, and haven't been able to find any help for this online.  Unless I just haven't yet found the right document, it is my understanding and experience that the online MDSplus documentation is notoriously incomplete and/or out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found out that there is no lower limit to the shot number in an MDSplus tree except 0.  Using -1 as the shot number is a way of referring to the model tree itself, and I don't think negative shot numbers have any meaning.

What presented the appearance of such a setting was that:

1. You have to call createPulse() in Python before storing new shot data;
2. Our MDSplus server was configured to do this automatically for each incremental shot number going forward;
3. Our MDSplus server was NOT configured to automatically create pulses when attempting to archive historical shot data.

Therefore pulses had already been created for shot numbers above a certain number, which had been determined through my usage pattern.

In case you encounter this problem yourself, you can write a node_exists(name, shot) method to find out if a node has already been created for a certain data point and shot number, then call createPulse() only when node_exists() returns false, e.g.:

```
import MDSplus as mds
if not node_exists(data_name, shot_num):
    tree = mds.Tree(tree_name, shot_num, tree_mode)
    tree.getNode(data_name).include_in_pulse=True
    tree.createPulse(shot_num)
```

Then go ahead and store your shot data.

Sorry for the confusion...